# mex file matlab. Libsvm error

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I tried compiling .c files to .mex , everything goes well and mex files are created but still it gives me the following errors. can anybody explain what is .exp file and why its giving me error?

Could Not Find E:\research data\libsvm-3.21\libsvm-3.21\matlab\svmtrain.exp

Could Not Find E:\research data\libsvm-3.21\libsvm-3.21\matlab\svmtrain.exp
MEX completed successfully.
Building with 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)'.

Could Not Find E:\research data\libsvm-3.21\libsvm-3.21\matlab\svmpredict.exp

Could Not Find E:\research data\libsvm-3.21\libsvm-3.21\matlab\svmpredict.exp
MEX completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be caused by the different version of the C++ compiler.

I solved this problem by chooseing the C++ 2010 compiler.

To setup the compiler, type `"mex -setup"` first then type `"mex -setup:I:\matlab2014b_win7\installation(root of your matlab installation)\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc2010.xml"`

> MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C)' for C language compilation.
>   Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
>        variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. In the near future
>        you will be required to update your code to utilize the
>        new API. You can find more information about this at:
>        http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

To choose a different C compiler, select one from the following:

- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (C)
  mex -setup:I:\matlab2014b_win7\installation\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc2010.xml C
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C)
  mex -setup:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014b\mex_C_win64.xml C
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional (C)
  mex -setup:I:\matlab2014b_win7\installation\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc2013.xml C